# Authorize Attribute Tied to Account Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have tracked this down to an issue with OWIN, in a new mvc project using the template everything works, however; when adding owin support to the existing / empty project the account controller gets called instead of what I have defined in the ConfigureAuth method of Startup.Auth.cs

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/users/Login") //THIS ALWAYS GOES TO THE ACCOUNT CONTROLLER
        });
```

Contoller

```
 [Authorize]
    public ActionResult TestMethodThatRequiredAuth()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Version 4 or 5? it is a known issue in version 3.

Comment: I am currently using MVC 5

Comment: To Lars, I expect it to hit the users controller man :)